# How to use set timeout using redux

Tags: angular, redux, settimeout

I have to display alert message before 5 mins of token expiration time.
I have already tried this solution.

```
showTokenExpiryAlert() {
    /* Convert expiresIn (seconds) to expiresIn (miliseconds) */
    const expiresIn = this.expiresIn * 1000;

    /* calculate alert time from expiresIn (miliseconds) */
    const alertTime = expiresIn - 300000;

    /* Show alert message before 5 mins of token expiry time */
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('Token will be exppired soon');
    }, alertTime);
  }
```

This code is working fine. But, it fails on page refresh. So, I'm thinking to use redux, but not getting exact solution how to use redux for this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try to put alertTime in sessionStorage or localstorage. It might help you.

Comment: No error.... But i'm using this settimeout on login page. So, when i 'm accessing another page and refresh it, settimeout does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to move the logic of display of expiration alert inside a component which always exists(say a `header-component`) but only activated after a successful login. Your login component sets the expiration time in localStorage after a successful login and sets a flag so that the `headerComponent` can be initialized. Your header component reads the value from `localStorage` and starts a timer.

```
showTokenExpiryAlert() {
    /* Convert expiresIn (seconds) to expiresIn (miliseconds) */
    const expiresIn = localStorage.getItem('expiresIn') * 1000;

    /* calculate alert time from expiresIn (miliseconds) */
    const alertTime = expiresIn - 300000;

    if (alertTime > 0) {
        /* Only show the alert if the token hasn't already expired */
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('Token will be exppired soon');
        }, alertTime);
    }
    else {
       localStorage.removeItem('expiresIn');  // token already expired
       // navigate to login
    }
  }
```

Don't use SessionStorage instead of localStorage, that will get cleared on a browser close.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use ngrx as Redux implementation for Angular:

1. By default, ngrx/store keeps all state in memory, so with full page reload you will loose whole app state anyway, even using redux.
2. You can try to [save whole ngrx app state in localStorage](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage), but that's much wider task in case you need just to check if token expired

So it may be better idea to do what @Aarsh proposed above.

Create service that:

1. Stores expiration time in localStorage and starts timer
2. Re-reads expiration time from localStorage on Application Start (page reload) and restarts timer if expiration time already there